# Rails 3 : how to improve my searchkick system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I've followed the excellent tuto about searchkick which I do recommend : https://github.com/ankane/searchkick
However I haven't found something to improve my searching engine :
For example if I have one user called :

```
"John"
```

If my search query is "Jo" that works, but if it is "hn" that does not..
Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: This isn't the answer you are looking for, but I don't think "hn" should ever match to "John".

Comment: well "John" contains "hn" though :)

Comment: It just isn't expected behavior.  If you start typing 'he' into google, you will get words that **start** with 'he'.  The list doesn't include 'cheat' just because it contains 'he'.  The idea of elastic search is to try to guess what your user wants and matching 'cheat' most likely isn't what the user is looking for.

Comment: that's a valid point Josh, I wanted to make it look like a regex or something.. it doesn't really make sense though.

Comment: In fact , if you wanna search for John.jpg , that may be usefull : this would be searching with a file extension filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible using [partial searches](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#partial-matches) in **searchkick**.